# How do I get rid of unwanted surface area?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, subdivision-surface

I'm making this can tab area for the top of my can, in which I had to create a trench for additional detail of the mesh.

The problem is marked with the red circle in the second picture.

Somehow when I turn on the subsurf modifier it kind of creates this unwanted geometry, kind of an overlap. What is the cause of this and the best way to get rid of it?

[image: e1]
[image: e2]

Best

[image]

Comment: I guess you need to create a good topology with quads etc...

Comment: Why not use a Mirror modifier? The can is symmetrical, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You have some concave N-gons collapsing in unexpected ways.

You should study your topology and cut up any faces that have more than 4 edges. This isn't the only place you have it, but it's the only place where the broken geometry is immediately visible

To cut a face, select the 2 points you want to cut trough and press <kbd>J</kbd>.

You may also find it useful to use the <kbd>K</kbd>nife tool.

Answer (score -2):

The right side seems to be correct, even thought the left isn't. You might have some verts that are connected, or you need to add some supporting edgeloops.

I'd delete the overlapping face, then manually add in those edges/faces with "F". Merge by distance at the end just to be safe. Check to ensure everything is kosher by seeing if you have any non-manifold geometry. (Edit Mode>Select> Select by Trait> Nonmaniold Geometry)

Assuming this is a water-tight mesh, you can also add the following stack of modifiers to get some clean bevels once everything is taken care of.

- Subdivision (Catmull-Clark) LV:2 Render:2
- Remesh (Voxel) Voxel size 0.1mm
- CorrectiveSmooth: Factor .5 Repeat: 100 Scale: 1.0 Smooth Type Length Weight
- Decimate (Collapse) RatioL 0.1.

That will give you smooth edges, remesh to get even topology all over, smooth out the rougher bits, then decimate them to be workable in the viewport. If you do that, know that it'll take about 2.5 minutes to compile, due to the Decimation Modifier having to handle all the others.